# Simulated click on "add more value" button of multi value cck field causes whole content form to submit

Tags: jquery, forms, drupal, cck

Hi I have a multi value cck field in my cck content type. I want to simulate click on "add another item" using jquery. which is like

$('#edit-field-supp-quan-field-supp-quan-add-more').trigger('click');

but it causes whole content form to submit instead of adding extra multi value cck field.

Manuall clicks are working perfectly. Can anyone tell me why behavior of manual clicks and simulated clicks are different.
thanks

----Update ----
This is the code I was using:-

$('#edit-field-freightamount-0-value').click(function(){

alert('hello');

$('#edit-field-supp-quan-field-supp-quan-add-more').trigger('click');

//$('.form-submit ahah-processed').trigger('click');

});

I actually intended to call this from inside some other function but I just wanted to test it before that . So i wrote this dummy  function which is like if i click inside a texrfield it should simulate a click on "add more item"

How do we prevent default action of click?

Comment: Can you show the code for your click function?  You do prevent the default action of the click right?

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem.
The answer is simple enough, use mousedown instead of click :)

```
$('#edit-field-supp-quan-field-supp-quan-add-more').trigger('mousedown');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return false;
```

at the end of your click function.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#edit-field-freightamount-0-value').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#edit-field-freightamount-0-value').click(function(e){
```

then put

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in the click handler function.