# drupal form trigger add more javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have a node add form with a field that has an 'add more' button. This particular field needs to be populated dynamically. Why doesn't it work to trigger a jquery click on the 'add more' button (`$('#edit-field-roof-area-und-add-more').click();`)? If I do that in the console, it returns an empty array.

What is the simplest way to create one or two fields in a node add form that I can add an unlimited amount to dynamically from the client side (the values come from a JS application.)

Comment: do you have an example jsfiddle or codepen so we can see exactly what your seeing to better help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it!! `jQuery('#edit-field-phone-no-und-add-more').trigger('mousedown')` Also, the ID changes each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

when adding nodes you might want to look into using context in your handler:

```
$('#edit-field-roof-area-und-add-more', 'body').click();
```

since the elements i dynamically created after the DOM is loaded.. try that, since the body tag is already present in the DOM when the page loads

and/or provide a jsfiddle or codepen example to better help you more...

**EDIT:**

you could also try this jQuery **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**:

```
 $('#edit-field-roof-area-und-add-more', 'body').trigger("click");
```

or  jQuery [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/):

```
 $('#edit-field-roof-area-und-add-more', 'body').triggerHandler("click");
```

the difference between the two is that triggerHandler does not bubble up the DOM

**also do have an example jsfiddle or codepen..** of your click event handler you are trying to trigger?

Comment: your JQuery snipped returns `Object[input#edit-field-phone-no-und-add-more.field-add-more-submit attribute value = "Add another item"]`http://stackoverflow.com/q/2788393?rq=1

Comment: I did get something back, but I don't understand why a javascript/jquery `click()` is interpreted differently by the browser than a physical mouse click.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `.trigger("click");` returned `Object[input#edit-field-phone-no-und-add-more.field-add-more-submit attribute value = "Add another item"]`, while the `.triggerHandler("click");` returned `false`. As far as the event handler, it would be something like $('#edit-field-phone-no-und-0-value').value('variable from JS app');
When I click the final `submit` function, it would include my other form fields.

Comment: not yet - I've looked around a lot, and I don't think I can do it directly. I'm going to try to do it through a custom module, and a hook-form-alter or something. I don't know yet. It doesn't make sense as to why a `click()` event doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting closer - I found a site that uses straight Javascript - no JQuery. The link is: http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2011/11/29/programatically-fire-crossbrowser-click-event-with-javascript/ It just reloads the whole browser instead of doing an AJAX event.